# What is the best practice for publishing settings without private data?

Tags: json, github, private-key

I have a `settings.json` file containing a bunch of information including `username` and `password` for the application I'm creating. Something like:

```
{
    "application": {
        "username": "someuser",
        "password": "somepassword",
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to software development especially making open source applications and deploying them so I would like to know what is the best practice in this case. Let's say I'm publishing it on GitHub and I would like the `settings.json` to be available as well with the correct structure but not containing my private data. However, I would like to have it locally with the data because I use it for testing.
Should I have two files maybe `settings-local.json` and `settings-prod.json` or what?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `example-settings.json` file with dummy data in it.

Have as many `settings-ENVIRONMENT-NAME.json` files as you have different environments.

Add `settings-*` to your `.gitignore` file so that real credentials do not get published by accident.

Include clear instructions (e.g. in your README) on how to name the real settings files.